# Can advanced installer check for updates in its original install location

Tags: .net, advanced-installer

I use a Visual Studio 2017 Installer Project to create an MSI for my project. I also create clickonce packages because of their autoupdate

This is because I have 3 types of users;

1. Users that want access to the latest version - this I can make work with advanced installer
2. Corporate users that distribute their own updates automatically and simply
3. Corporate users that update using an MSI

For 2. I use the clickonce 'feature' that you can configure it so that it looks for updates in the location it was installed from. This works REALLY well for my clients that want to control their updates rather than have them automagically available from my website. I dont need to make packages for individual businesses with their specific URL, I just give them the installer and they run it from a share. When an update is accepted, they just replace it.

But I have finally kicked clickonce to the kerb. Too many times the update just decides to not work on specific machines for no decipherable reason. It is truly a horrible technology.

I am looking instead at advanced installer which appears to do everything I need - except the update from install location. Is this possible? Or do I need to configure the location in the installer. If the update URL has to be explicitly provided, can it be provided via a config file, or do I need different packages for every different update URL?

Answer (score 1):

With Advanced Installer you can set the updates location at install time using data from user input. For instance you can use a property reference in "Updater" view of your project. Then at install time set the above property to the location value get from user. This way the installed Updater tool will search for updates in the location set by user at install time.

Then when delivering updates to your user network you should just instruct him to copy the updates in the location configured at install time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: OK - I get the principle, but it is not practical for the user to have to enter it. In a corporate environment, I want the user to be given the location they can run the installer from. They should not have to input anything. Is it possible to have the installer set the property as the location from which the file is installed automatically?

Comment: Yes, I think this can be done too. Just try to use the SOURCEDIR (when using an MSI package type) or SETUPEXEDIR (when using an EXE setup type) properties.